# Еще по тому же предложению

Tags: грамотная-речь

Предложение из предыдущего вопроса: "И это при том, что я был обычный советский мальчишка, и до этого мне всегда снились светлые, очень добрые и радостные сны". Правильно ли сформулировано: был кто или был кем? То есть, "был мальчишка" или "был мальчишкой"? Или можно и так, и так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rusgram.ru/:
Форма именительного падежа употребляется тогда, когда речь идет о **постоянном** признаке, присущем носителю на протяжении длительного промежутка времени.

"Я был обычный мальчишка" - слова ОБЫЧНЫЙ МАЛЬЧИШКА употреблены в им.п., так как именная часть выражает признак, который был присущ носителю длительное время. 
Если признак временный, то чаще используется творительный падеж. В Вашем предложении, мне кажется, можно употребить и ту и другую форму без всякого ущерба для смысла. Ср.:Я был обычный мальчишка. - Я был обычным мальчишкой.